# php - Detect bad request

Tags: php, arrays, json, request

I have 2 JSON sources and one of them reply 400 Bad request (depend of charge in servers)
So I want that my php code check the answer of both server and select working one

```
<?php
$server1 = 'server1.lan'
$server2 = 'server2.lan'

/*
Here a code to check and select the working server
*/

$json=file_get_contents('https://'.$workingServer.'/v1/data?source='.$_GET['source']);
$data =  json_decode($json);
if (count($data->data)) {

        // Cycle through the array
        foreach ($data->data as $idx => $data) {
echo "<p>$data->name</p>\n";
?>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an idea of what you may want to implement. Your goal is to get that idea and implement something like that in your own way, with a normal error handling and removal of code duplication:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://server1.lan/v1/data');
if ($json === false) 
{
    $json = file_get_contents('https://server2.lan/v1/data');
    if ($json === false) 
    {
        die('Both servers are unavailable');
    }
}
```

[`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) returns boolean `false` on failure, so if the first server is unavailable, call the second. If it is also unavailable, exit the script, or do some sort of error handling that you prefer.

You may want to create an array of possible server names, and use a function that iterates over all of them until it finds a working one, and returns the contents, or throws an exception on failure.

I would also suggest that you use [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), which gives you an option to see the error codes of the request, customize the request itself, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Check `$http_response_header` after making the `file_get_contents` call.

```
$json = file_get_contents(('https://'.$server1.'/v1/data?source='.$_GET['source']);

if (strpos($http_response_header[0],"400") > 0)
{
  $json = file_get_contents(('https://'.$server.'/v1/data?source='.$_GET['source']);
}
```

See examples at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php